# How to pass canvas stream to another window since createObjectURL is deprecated?

Tags: javascript, canvas, websocket, stream, blob

I'm building a very specific project that has the following:

- A main window with a canvas element.
- A second window opened from the main one (window.open(...)) which gets a webcam stream and draws it on a canvas.

I need to draw the same canvas, realtime, on the canvas in the main window. What I am doing now is on my second window, I do  `window.URL.createObjectURL(canvasStream)` which gives me a blob url I can use in the main window to get the feed and draw it back on the main canvas.

This all works *(read worked)* very well but now the `URL.createObjectURL` fonction is deprecated and cannot be used anymore. This means I can't get a blob url to pass to my main window anymore...

How could I pass that canvas stream to my main window without using this fonction? I know I could maybe use Websocket to send the frames from one canvas to another but I found it not as reliable and less consistent. It also adds another layer of complexity that could fail.

**Note:** the project will run in a `nw.js` bundle so there are no problems to enable flags and things like that.

**Note 2:** I know I can stay on an older version of `nw.js` which has `URL.createObjectURL` not deprecated but it is not a good solution for the future.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What makes you think `URL.createObjectURL` is deprecated? I don't see any indication of that [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) or [in the media source extensions](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/#dom-url-createobjecturl). And I don't see anything about that function in the `nw.js` documentation [at all](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=createobjecturl) (in case the deprecation was `nw.js`-specific).

Comment: Just by calling the function you can see it in the console.
`[Deprecation] URL.createObjectURL with media streams is deprecated and will be removed in M68, around July 2018. Please use HTMLMediaElement.srcObject instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5618491470118912 for more details.`

Comment: And if you check the link: `This functionality has been deprecated in 2013 and superseded by assigning streams to srcObject.`

Comment: Okay, so the function isn't deprecated, using it on media elements is (odd the spec doesn't say that; my link above was outdated, but [the current one](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/#dom-url-createobjecturl) doesn't either). So have you tried doing what they suggest in the deprecation issues (assigning directly to `srcObject`)?

Comment: As it is in another window I can't assign it to my video element on my main window. I haven't found a way. Right now I assing the created blob URL to my video element in my main window to get the feed

Comment: Is that an `nw.js` thing? Because you can certainly use objects from one window in another on browsers in general (including webkit), provided there's no Same Origin Policy issue, which I assume there wouldn't be *within* an nw.js app.

Comment: Could you please give me an example? If I use something like `myCanvas.srcObject`and assign it to a variable or something. How could I access that variable from my main window?

Comment: You'd use [messaging](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#web-messaging) (if the media element is *transferrable*) or in the worst case, remember that most global variables are properties on the window object, and your two windows each have references to each other (the main window via the return value of `window.open`, the other window via `opener`). (The WHAT-WG messaging section is the most up-to-date, but the [old working group doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/) may be more accessible).

Comment: Oh my god you are right... I completely forgot I could access the opened window variables directly by simply using `myWindow.(var name here)`... I don't even need to use postMessage or something

Comment: @T.J.CrowderT.J what is deprecated is passing it a MediaStream. It is still very valid to set a blobURL to a MediaElement, but only if pointing to an MSE or a Blob, because in the case of MediaStream, and particullarly of MS comming from a device (getUserMedia) createObjectURL will lock the device the whole life of the blobURI.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the received comments, I have managed to make this work.

I did not realise you could access variables from the opened window directly in the parent window.

Really basic code example to access variables from opened window, in the parent window.

```
// In the parent
var myWindow = window.open(url);

// In the child window
var myVar = "test";

// In the parent
console.log(myWindow.myVar); // => "test"
```

This means you just need to create your canvas/video stream in the child window and you can apply it to your element in your main window by doing something like:

```
// In the child window
var canvasEl = document.querySelector("canvas");
var canvasStream = canvasEl.captureStream(30);

// In the parent
var videoEl = document.querySelector("video");
videoEl.srcObject = myWindow.canvasStream;
```

The canvas in your main window will then show the samething as the canvas in your child window.

Comment: And if you need to support older browsers, or even just want to avoid video artifacts, you could also just drawImage the canvas in your main thread to an other canvas in the popup in a rAF loop.

Comment: @Kaiido Good point, that is what I think I'll end up doing. It also has better performances that way.