# How can I duplicate a media stream to a popup window?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediastream, get-display-media, broadcast-channel

I want to start a screen share in my main tab by calling `getDisplayMedia`, and then clone it to another popup window which I open from my app (using `window.open`), effectively showing the screen capture twice, in parallel.

According to [this](https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter/issues/636#issuecomment-388619724) thread, [this snippet](https://codepen.io/amiregelz/pen/OJRvoPp?editors=1010) should work - but it doesn't:

```
async function startCapture() {
  return await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
}

function openPopup() {
  startCapture().then((stream) => {
    let video = document.getElementById("source");
    video.srcObject = stream;
    let popUpWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "x=y");
    let videoElem = document.createElement("video");
    videoElem.autoplay = true;
    let remoteVideo = popUpWindow.document.body.appendChild(videoElem);
    remoteVideo.srcObject = stream;
  });
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kaiido mentioned in the comments, the issue was I needed to add the `muted` attribute to the destination video for it to play when automatically when duplicating the stream.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

> **Autoplay availability**
> As a general rule, you can assume that media
> will be allowed to autoplay only if at least one of the following is
> true:
>
> - The audio is muted or its volume is set to 0
> - The user has interacted
>   with the site (by clicking, tapping, pressing keys, etc.)
> - If the site
>   has been whitelisted; this may happen either automatically if the
>   browser determines that the user engages with media frequently, or
>   manually through preferences or other user interface features
> - If the autoplay feature policy is used to grant autoplay support to a  and its document. Otherwise, the playback will likely be
>   blocked. The exact situations that result in blocking, and the
>   specifics of how sites become whitelisted vary from browser to
>   browser, but the above are good guidelines to go by.

Answer (score 2):

No, not directly, because a `MediaStreamTrack` is not transferable. It's tied to the document it's created in.

A workaround would be to establish an `RTCPeerConnection` between the two tabs and transmit the screen-capture track from the tab that has it to the tab that doesn't. This should be relatively performant since the bits never leave your network card.

You can use a `BroadcastChannel` for the necessary signaling to establish such a connection, or do tricks with `localStorage` to do the signaling like I do [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/80xcgwmc/show) using a camera,  but it works with any source (open in two tabs first, then click the `Call` button in one).

A limitation of this workaround is that if you close the original tab then you lose both tracks.

Comment: Not sure it applies to OP but with the same limitation (if original doc dies the stream dies) with arguably less coding, they can also probably pass it to the other tab through WindowProxy if that tab was `open`ed. And nitpick, but BCChannels don't do transfer anyway.

Comment: @jib @Kaiido
I stumbled upon [this thread](https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter/issues/636).
Since both windows are same origin, is it possible to use the mechanism described [here](https://medium.com/hackernoon/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202) and use the same `ref` or set the `srcObject` of both the original and the copy video elements to the same stream in order to achieve this?

Comment: @jib Do you it's possible? which approach is better?

Comment: @amiregelz you'd need the second tab to be `open`ed by the first document, i.e using `window.open()`. If it has been created by an other mean (e.g the user typed the address in the address bar), then you won't be able to make the two windows communicate directly enough so they can pass the track or stream.

Comment: @Kaiido That's exactly how I open it - with `window.open()` - but I still can't manage to set the stream to the video object of the popup window I open. I'm doing this in React. Do you have an example of how to do it?

Comment: @amiregelz not a react one no, but in bare Web API see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227332/continue-recording-with-getdisplaymedia-on-page-after-reload/65230020#65230020) to a related question

Comment: @Kaiido Also tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237238/how-to-pass-canvas-stream-to-another-window-since-createobjecturl-is-deprecated) (just with opposite direction to clone the video to the popup) and it also didn't work.

Comment: @Kaiido According to [this](https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter/issues/636#issuecomment-388619724) thread, [this CodePen should work](https://codepen.io/amiregelz/pen/OJRvoPp?editors=1010) - but it doesn't. What am I missing??

Comment: @amiregelz this codepen works fine on Chrome (Firefox won't allow the capture request to be made from that iframe). But you are never asking the video in the popup to start playing, so you need to right-click -> show controls -> scroll down to the controls and click play.

Comment: @Kaiido I want it to autoplay, can I do it with code?

Comment: Just add the `muted` attribute.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you!!! I never thought this is the reason it's not working. I really appreciate your help :)